# Any Possible to get A4 page size at jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get Page height while Print, like this  Image [image: **Check This Image**]

currently tried the code, I Get Each `li` height and added. then total Height reached that **limit** `wrapAll`with `col-md-6`

```
 var $records = $('#two_column li'),
          total = 0,
          group = 0;
         limit = 1118.73; //px

  if (total > limit) {
    total = $record.outerHeight(true);
    group++;
  }

for (var i = 0; i <= group; i++) {
     $('[data-group="' + i + '"]').wrapAll('<div class="col-md-6"></div>')
}
```

My Problem was, **I can't to get Page height(limit) while Print**

Limit value need  A4 page Height

Comment: Some HTML for context would be helpful